# Adding quantitative values to differentiate data through colours in a scatterplot's legend in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Currently, I'm working on an introductory paper on data manipulation and such; however... the CSV I'm working on has some things I wish to do a scatter graph on!

I want a scatter graph to show me the volume sold on certain items as well as their average price, differentiating all data according to their region (Through colours I assume).

So what I want is to know if I can add the region column as a quantitative value
[image]

or if there's a way to make this possible...
It's my first time using Python and I'm confused way too often

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but here is some working code, assuming you have data in the format of `[(country, volume, price), ...]`. If not, you can change the inputs to the `scatter` method as needed.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_countries = 50
# get the data into "countries", for example
countries = ...
# in this example: countries is [('BS', 21, 25), ('WZ', 98, 25), ...]
df = pd.DataFrame(countries)


# arbitrary method to get a color
def get_color(i, max_i):
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
    return cmap(i/max_i)

# get the figure and axis - make a larger figure to fit more points
# add labels for metric names
def get_fig_ax():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.set_xlabel('volume')
    ax.set_ylabel('price')
    return fig, ax


# switch around the assignments depending on your data
def get_x_y_labels():
    x = df[1]
    y = df[2]
    labels = df[0]
    return x, y, labels

offset = 1       # offset just so annotations aren't on top of points
x, y, labels = get_x_y_labels()
fig, ax = get_fig_ax()

# add a point and annotation for each of the labels/regions
for i, region in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(region, (x[i] + offset, y[i] + offset))
    # note that you must use "label" for "legend" to work
    ax.scatter(x[i], y[i], color=get_color(i, len(x)), label=region)

# Add the legend just outside of the plot.
# The .1, 0 at the end will put it outside
ax.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1, .1, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with 50 points]